# Unable to connect to tfs: The server committed a protocol violation

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have vs2012 and vs2013 installed on my computer and using tfs 2012. recently when I want to connect to tfs I got this error message:

> TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server:
>   `http://MyIpAddress:8080/tfs.`
>
> Possible reasons for failure include:
>
> - The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
> - The Team Foundation Server is offline.
> - The password has expired or is incorrect.
>
> Technical information (for administrator):
>
> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

I checked all the possible reasons mentioned but there was nothing wrong with them. I tried connecting to tfs using another computer in our network and my own account and it was OK. I can't find what's wrong with my own none of my vs instances can connect to tfs which I was using for months.
I don't know how to fix this, any idea?

Comment: what happens if you paste your tfs address into chrome or IE? Can you ping your server?

Comment: @Snorre Yes, I can login to tfs using web access.

Comment: I had similar problems once that was caused by an antivirus/web proxy (Symantec) that had gone bananas.

Comment: @Snorre I'm using windows 8.1 with default anti virus(windows defender and I tried disabling it but still have the problem.

Comment: Check if you have event ID 9000 errors in Event Log on the server. This could be because TFS cache is getting reset because it reaches size limit.

Comment: @AdarshShah I checked it but there is not such an error.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your VCS root URL to:
 https://abc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
and 
with combination of Alternate credential option.(##LIVE##...)

Answer (score 0):

> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

Error went away when I changed the port of TFS server from 80 to 8080. This proved the problem was due to port conflict as mentioned in other online posts e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117038/while-getting-latest-files-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section)