# While getting latest files - the server committed a protocol violation. section=responsestatusline TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

When i try to get bunch of files from the TFS server, i am getting error - 
"the server committed a protocol violation. section=responsestatusline"

At the same time if try to get single file which gave this error then does not show any error.
I have done some research, it says some ports on my machine are in use. But i don't know how to detect those ports and free them?

Thanks
Fahad Mullaji

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that some of the ports of my machine were in use with some of the unnecessary(ads) program installed.

Uninstalled couple of program which were not needed or could be exchanging data on internet.

Now i am not facing that problem. Hope this will help for people who are facing same issue.

Thanks
Fahad Mullaji

Comment: Indeed; this can happen when you're running a crazy proxy that munges the traffic.  Some anti-virus or malware scanning programs can do this.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I had an IP in adapter settings (networking), once its set to "obtain DNS Server address automatically" then TFS start downloading the data without error.

Hope it Helps,

Answer (score 0):

In my case TFS was configured to listen at port 80. From Visual Studio and commend line (tf.exe) had exactly the same issue in getting latest as mentioned in the question.

To ascertain it's port issue, I changed the port to 8080 in TFS server and the problem went away.